# Not getting any results

Tags: python

I am trying to write code to find the length of a string, and to return "invalid entry" when an integer is entered.

```
def length_of_string(mystring):
    if type(mystring) == int:
        return "invalid entry"
    else:
        mystring = input("enter the string ")
        return len(mystring)
```

When I try to execute this function it doesn't give me an error, nor does it produce any solution.

Comment: How do you call that funcion from `main()`?

Comment: First, are you printing the results? Second, why pass one string and then input another one?

Comment: Why would the type of a string ever be an int? A string is a string, not an int.

Answer (score 2):

You should move out `mystring = input("enter the string ")` from `else` and call the function from main or other place.

```
def length_of_string(mystring):
    if type(mystring) is int:
        return "invalid entry"
    else:
        return len(mystring)


mystring = input("enter the string ")
print(length_of_string(mystring))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string to be always requested from the user:

```
def length_of_string():
    mystring = input("enter the string ")
    try:
        int(mystring)
        return "invalid entry"
    except ValueError:
        return len(mystring)

print(length_of_string())
```

If you want to use the function with a parameter:

```
def length_of_string(mystring):
    try:
        int(mystring)
        return "invalid entry"
    except ValueError:
        return len(mystring)

print(length_of_string("a string")) # prints 8
print(length_of_string(1))          # prints invalid entry
print(length_of_string(input("enter the string "))) # prints [input length]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not called the function.  Functions (similar to classes) do not run until you execute them.

Calling them is easy.  You just have to call the function name.  You also have to pass the necessary parameters to the function (here it is `mystring`).

```
length_of_string('Hello World')
```

To get what is returned you will need to pass it to a variable or print it/perform some other action.

```
print(length_of_string('Hello World'))
```

Also `if type(mystring) == int:` will not work `input()` is always a string.  The thing to do is to test it and see if it can be made into an integer:

```
try: 
    int(mystring)
    return "invalid entry"
except ValueError:
    mystring = input("enter the string ")
    return len(mystring)
```

Entire code:

```
def length_of_string(mystring):
    try: 
        int(mystring)
        return "invalid entry"
    except ValueError:
        mystring = input("enter the string ")
        return len(mystring)
print(length_of_string('Hello World'))
```

Comment: I tried running that code but that gives me a error message

PS C:\Users\ayudr\Desktop\python> python .\exercise3.py
  File ".\exercise3.py", line 2
    return "invalid entry"
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
PS C:\Users\ayudr\Desktop\python> python .\exercise3.py
  File ".\exercise3.py", line 4
    return len(mystring)

Comment: @steffinissac  I added the complete code.  Try it again, there was no error for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a string by parameter, it does not make sense to overwrite it again.
I think the solution is:

```
def length_of_string(mystring):
    if (isinstance(mystring, str)):
        print "Length of the string: ", len(mystring)
    else:
        print "Type invalid"
```

Comment: how do i define a statement where it can check for the interger value and return a invlid entry message